# Can I cancel the DataGridView.CellMouseDoubleClick Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mouseevent

I am unable to find set the CancelEventArgs property for the DataGridView.CellMouseDoubleClick event.

Is there anyway at all that I can cancel the event?

Why is there no CancelEventArgs property?

Answer (score 4):

Because [`DataGridView.CellMouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellmousedoubleclick.aspx) has [`DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellmouseeventargs.aspx), but you can `return` at the very beginning (of method) when event starts executing (if it meets your specific condition of course).

Comment: Like this in the event:

if(yourCondition) return;
//else: execute doubleclick-related code